# syntax error using SET with named placeholders

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to update an arbitrary column in a table as so:

```
cursor.execute('update table set :n = :v where submitter = :s', 
               {'n':'col1', 'v': 10, 's': 'mike'})
```

But it gives me `sqlite3.OperationalError: near ":n": syntax error`. Oddly it works fine when I do

```
cursor.execute('update table set col1 = :v where submitter = :s', 
               {'n':'col1', 'v': 10, 's': 'mike'})
```

Why can't I seem to name columns in an injection-save way? Is there some other way to set an arbitrary column?

Comment: What is `:n` going to be replaced with in the final SQL statement? Text with quotes around it, basically. Will text with quotes around it work as a column name? No.

Answer (score 4):

Only *values* can be bound; *identifiers* (e.g. column/table names) and other structural syntax cannot be bound with placeholders.

In general a prepared statement *must* have a "known query shape" and allowing dynamic identifiers would prohibit that. (There may be databases and database adapters that don't hold to this, but I have yet to meet one.)

Answer (score 2):

Placeholders cannot, as you have discovered, be used as table or column names. Instead, you have to concatenate in a string for the dynamic table or column name.

It is therefore recommended to check it against a whitelist of available column names to be sure it is safe:

```
# Array of valid values for colname
valid_colnames = ['col1','col2','col3']
# Only do it if you received a safe known value
if colname in valid_colnames:
  cursor.execute('update table set ' + colname + ' = :v where submitter = :s', 
               {'v': 10, 's': 'mike'})
```

Comment: not an A+ for elegance, but as it happens I'm iterating over columns anyway, so I guess this works.

Comment: @Shep If you want to get fancy, you can query SQLite for the column names available on that table and use those in an array, but this still limits to the columns you would actually permit modifications to so its a bit easier.